# make mode inherit multiple foreign keys on creation

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models named: **PaymentMode** and **Store as**:

**PaymentMode Model:** (id will be auto generated by django)

```
id = model.IntegerField(primarykey)
name = model.CharField("eg: cash, debit, credit")
```

**Store Model:** (id will be auto generated by django)

```
id = model.IntegerField(primarykey)
payment_mode = model.ForeignKey(Paymentmode, on_delete=model.cascade)
mode_credit_value = model.IntegerField(default=0)
name = model.CharField()
... some other fields
```

So what i want is whenever a store is created, all payment modes inherits automatically, inherit all foreign keys, this will make multiple rows in store table as: (if store with id 1 is added, 3 rows for 1, similarly for other)

```
store_id | payment_mode | name
------------------------------
1             1           abcd
1             2           abcd
1             3           abcd
... similarly if store id 2 is passed, all master are inherited
2             1           xyz
2             2           xyz
2             3           xyz
```

i looked at various stackoverflow question, probably this might be duplicate, but those all overrides save function and make only one inherited object like:
[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108857/auto-create-model-with-foreign-key-when-model-is-created-django)
so the question is will save function override approach in above question inherit all foreign keys? or will it make only one?
Obviously payment modes will be created first. Also in future if a payment mode is added, is it possible to add new payment mode to all pre-existing stores automatically?

Probably my approach of creating model is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is many-to-many relationship (One store can have many payment modes and one payment mode can be attached to multiple stores). So you should use ManyToMany field.

So the store model will be like:

```
class Store(models.Model):
      payment_modes = models.ManytoManyField(PaymentMode)
```

**UPDATE:**

To add all the payment modes in the `Store` model, you can override the `save` method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    instance.payment_modes.add(*PaymentMode.objects.all())
    return instance
```

Now to save the payment modes in the store, you can either ask the user what are the available payment modes for the given store or if you know that all payment modes will be supported, then while saving the store fetch all the payment models and assign it to store.

The above approach will have one drawback that if any new payment mode is added then you have to run a script to add to all the previous stores.

Comment: how do i fetch all payment modes and assign? this is what i need help with, shall i do it via over riding save function and save multiple times?

Comment: Thanks @Ritesh Agarwal

Comment: I tried, in many to many i have duplicacy problem, via admin section a store can add sampe payment mide multiple times, i also want the relation to be unique for each store only

Comment: @AashishGahlawat If you are using `add` method to save m2m relation, then it adding second time will not create duplicate relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can define one more model

```
class AllPayemntModes(models.Model):
    modes = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentMode)
```

then add all payment modes to Store model and

```
class Store(models.Model):
    payment_modes = models.ForeignKey(AllPayementModes)
```

then whenever a new store is added you only have to add it to the **AllPayemntModes** the it will be available to all stores.
**specific_mode = store.payment_modes.modes.get(name=("cashcash/debi/credit)** will give you a specific mode.

Comment: can i directly use many-to-many on store itself as payment_modes = model.ManyToMany(PaymentMode) ?

Comment: @Aashish Gahlawat you can, the issue is that whenever you create a store you need to add all those methods to that field and whenever a new payment method is created you need go back and add that to all the stores again